# Django - pass exception to debugger

Tags: python, django, exception, wing-ide

Usually, Django outputs a nice HTML traceback page once something goes wrong. This is fine as long as I run the server directly, but now I'm trying to run Django using a Python debugger (Wing IDE in my case).

I can set breakpoints and it stops, but once an exception is thrown, the debugger doesn't breaks as Django handles the exception. What do I need to do in order to leave those exceptions unhandled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Notes on Debugger Configuration" in the following:  http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/django

Comment: Thank you. Problem perfectly solved. (shame on me for not looking there in the first place)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Except that maybe the information at the link stays current, while vendor-specific details put here could go stale.

Comment: @gknauth, Wingware have apparently chosen to use SO as a support channel, and then it's up to them to abide to the guidelines of the site.

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant Wingware has their own support mailing list, wiki, monitors FB/Twitter, etc.  SO is not their support site.  I don't see anything wrong with noticing a question and pointing out that the full answer is already somewhere else.  If they had to duplicate answers on every related SO page, it might cause them to avoid SO.  People can still vote their answers up or down.  Anyway leoluk seems happy.

Comment: I've been trying to not just link since the above comment.  I think it's reasonable to try to provide at least part of the answer directly on SO, although in some cases a link will be needed for detailed instructions.  And yes we just try to monitor SO for relevant questions but this is not our main support site.